More than one key in object for union../JSON object with type string does not match schema which expected object
Im trying to publish a message in pub sub to a topic linked to a bigquery subscription via GCP but something is wrong with my message format.
I encounter this error: "Invalid JSON-encoded message against Avro schema. Error: JSON object with type string does not match schema which expected object." if im publishing it this way:
{
  "severity": "INFO",
  "timetamp": 1728564577801,
  "message": null,
  "payload": "{\"key1\":\"value1\"}"
}

and this error: "Invalid JSON-encoded message against Avro schema. Error: More than one key in object for union." if im publishing it this way:
{
  "severity": "INFO",
  "timetamp": 1728564577801,
  "message": null,
  "payload": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}

This is the Avro schema:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "k8s_agent_logs_schema",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "severity",
      "type": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "timetamp",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "message",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "payload",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}

and this is the table schema:
enter image description here
Somebody has an idea?
